# How can I increase the height of a driveway edge at the gutter?

Tags: water, drain

My driveway is near the low end of our subdivision and slopes down from the gutter. Heavy rain brings water and sand on to my driveway. I have created a drain for the water, but the sand remains, lots of it.

I had a 5 ft. section the driveway concrete removed and replaced with new concrete to the gutter to increase the height by 2 inches. Unfortunately, contractor only got it to 1 1/2 inches. I need an additional inch of height, but the contractor won't help.

My thought is to find rubber coating that I can apply in several layers. The height would increase and the rubber coating would absorb some of the shock of the bump.  This problem has been brought up here before.

Comment: Links to the previous problems and why those solutions win’t work.

Comment: You may consider contacting the city about the situation, as well. There _should_ be a storm water drain at the low point to drain this water away. If there _is_ a drain, but it's not working, then it needs to be fixed. Both of these are city concerns. If you're on friendly enough terms with your neighbors, you might be able to recruit them to submit complaints to the city, as well. Even if it doesn't immediately and directly affect them, complaints from multiple people will probably get more and quicker attention than from 1 person.

Comment: Additionally, if you have it in writing that the contractor was to raise the surface by 2" but he only raised it by 1.5" you have an issue with the contractor. I hate to say "lawyer up", but that may be your only recourse in this situation. It's possible that just the mention of "I hate to have to get a lawyer involved..." might be motivating to the contractor to do what she promised.

Comment: I'd bag the sand and put it on the curb for five bucks apiece. In my experience, that kind of sand is perfect for kids' sandboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber coating won't provide enough height to be effective. You need at least an inch or two to change the course of a stream.

I think I'd look at a bolt-down speed bump, and I'd put foam "sill seal" underneath it to be sure to get a good seal against the driveway.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd try try some instant asphalt, you might need to add some white spirits or liquid tar to get it to stick to the concrete.